# how do i download youtube video through developers tools

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, google-chrome-devtools

This question is basically more about how does youtube player works...from network activity in chrome developer tools, i can see that something is streaming/octet...so flash player is taking stream and showing it.

But the video also gets cached so how can i download that file. It has to be somewhere. I have searched through internet all examples point to some flv file that doesn't exist anymore and the one that is in network is something else and not what i am looking for, main video file.

Comment: this used to be possible very very easy. Since the last chrome version, they have disabled it for some reason..

Comment: you used to be able to open up chromedevtools, go to the network tab and when you were on youtube, vimeo, other explicit video sites that no adult would ever think of going to ( ;) ), you would see the mp4 file beeing streamed.

Comment: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/download-youtube-media-without-tools

Answer (score 1):

Summary: (I'm skipping some basics, assuming familiarity with chrome-like dev tool panels) Visit network tab, search 'video' or 'audio', find a request videoplayback?..., copy its request link, remove `range=...` params, paste into browser. See more details at https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/download-youtube-media-without-tools